# scrape data from dropdown php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to **Scrape** dropdown data from this https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbRaceChartCalendar.cfm?SAP=TN
I use curl to create dom from Url

```
 <?php
    
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    
    
    function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
    
    $returned_content = get_data('https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbRaceChartCalendar.cfm?SAP=TN');
    
    echo $returned_content;
    ?>
```

When i get content like that it's not return the hole webpage. it's not returnning  middle part content(search aria and calander aria) of this page.
so i cant **Scrape** from Track,month,Year dropdown data because that part not return with curl. How return hole web page with curl with middle content

Comment: look at the HTML received by curl. it contains `We're having trouble loading your Captcha. Consider refreshing the page.
You reached this page when attempting to access https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbRaceChartCalendar.cfm?SAP=TN`
- robots have to complete a captcha or convincingly emulate a browser prior to scraping that page, your script does not attempt to detect nor account for the captcha page in any way, nor does it attempt to emulate a browser.

Comment: @hanshenrik can i avoid Captcha when scraping?  what do i need to do

Comment: browsers don't get the captcha, so you'll have to imitate a browser so your PHP script doesn't get the captcha either. so first step is to figure out what is the difference between your PHP request, and a real browser request. start a netcat server on port 9999, `nc -l -p 9999` , then go to `http://127.0.0.1:9999` , then do the same with your PHP script, what is different between the PHP request and your browser request? (there should be several headers sent by your browser that PHP doesn't send)

Comment: @hanshenrik i will try